# How to auto populate /etc/resolv.conf when using a static configuration

Tags: dns, resolv.conf

I'm on an IoT device running busybox with glibc. When I have a DHCP setup in `/etc/network/interfaces` then `udhcpc` atuomatically updates `/etc/resolv.conf`. I can see this by clearing `/etc/resolv.conf` and then starting `udhcpc`.

```
# udhcpc -i wlan0 --pidfile /tmp/udhpcp.pid
udhcpc: started, v1.26.2
udhcpc: sending discover
udhcpc: sending select for 172.20.53.151
udhcpc: lease of 172.20.53.151 obtained, lease time 46800
deleting routers
SIOCDELRT: No such process
adding dns 172.20.62.208
adding dns 172.20.108.123
```

However, when I have a static configuration setup in `/etc/network/interfaces` nothing updates `/etc/resolv.conf`. When can be done to have have a DNS server automatically added to `/etc/resolv.conf` when using a static IP configuration? Is this possible? Currently when this modules gets configured with a static IP no DNS hostname or IP is provided. Would it need to be provided if configured using a static IP?

**Edit:**

To further explain, the device gets its networks settings from an XML configuration file. This file has the four fields:

```
<NetworkConfig>
  <IP>1.2.3.4</IP>
  <NETMASK>255.255.240.0</NETMASK>
  <GATEWAY>1.2.3.1</GATEWAY>
  <DHCP>0</DHCP>
</NetworkConfig>
```

A program on the device takes this and generates a `/etc/network/interfaces` file, creating an entry like so if DHCP=0:

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
   address 1.2.3.4
   netmask 255.255.240.0
   gateway 1.2.3.1
```

And an entry like so if DHCP=1

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
```

So when trying to configure the device with a static IP, nothing updates `/etc/resolv.conf` and no DNS info is provided in the XML file. Is there no application which would be able to automatically updated `/etc/resolv.conf`? How/where does `udhcpc` get its dns info from?

Comment: A DHCP server can send the DNS servers' addresses to the client, so it can update `/etc/resolv.conf`. How do you get the correct configuration into `/etc/network/interfaces`? In a similar way you have to fill `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Comment: Currently the way the module works is an XML file is sent to the module and a program parses that and updates `/etc/network/interfaces`. That XML file doesn't have any DNS info and my understanding is that it would need to provided this if you're using a static IP configuration.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add more information instead of writing comments. To get help you should describe how your configuration mechanism works. If you use standard tools I suggest to show your scripts, input and output.

Comment: udhcpc gets its information from the dhcp reply. If you need to not used the dhcp reply information, you'll need to manually input all of its data, including ip address, netmask, gateway, dns servers, ntp servers, etc. It sounds like your XML is not up to the task that it's been given.

Answer (score 1):

udhcpc uses the script: `/usr/share/udhcpc/default.script` to configure your interface after getting a DHCP reply. There is a variable in the script: `$dns` which is an array of nameservers. You can edit the script to do whatever you like; including overwriting the `$dns` variable to be two nameservers of your choice i.e:

```
dns="8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4"
```

Source: http://forum.tinycorelinux.net/index.php?topic=8019.0